# Why are bacterial genomes limited in size compared to eukaryotic ones?

Tags: evolution, genomics, genomes

I was looking at this graph that shows that the eukaryotic genome has "no size limit" whilst the bacterial one does. Unfortunately the graph has no reference but essentially the idea is that most bacterial genomes are in the roughly 10^5 - 10^7.5 base pair range whilst eukaryotic genomes can be anything from 10^7 t 10^12 base pairs long for example and there is a lot more variation in genome size.

I was wandering where this limit for bacteria comes from? Specifically i**s eukaryotic DNA packing more efficient in eukaryotes than in bacteria** and therefore more genetic material can be safely carried? Or **does this have more to do with evolutionary constraints on bacterial genome size with smaller genomes being selected for**?